# $post in javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, symfony

I am working in Symfony2

in detail.js

```
function saveForm() {

    var url = $('#form_id').attr('action');
    $.post(
    url, $('#form_id').serialize(),
    function(data){}
    ).success(function(){
               alert("3");
    }
    ).error(function(){
               alert("4");
    });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form_id").submit(saveForm);
    });
```

in controler in one function

```
array('action' => $this->generateUrl('items_form_post2', array('id' => $id, 'redir' => 'items_detail')),
      'attr' => array('id' => 'form_id'),));
```

in web is still `alert(4)`   error function, but I dont know why

in firebug

```
POST ......./app_dev.php/post-detail-form/173/items_detail

   Accept   */*
   Accept-Encoding  gzip, deflate
   Accept-Language  cs,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
   Content-Length   344
   Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
   Cookie   .....
   Host ....
   Referer  .....
   User-Agent   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
   X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
   error                 ++++++++ it is console.log(textStatus);
   e00bb3...il_1.js
   (an empty string)     ++++++++ it is console.log(errorThrown);
   e00bb3...il_1.js
```

I didnt see any response like JSON

--------------------------------SOLUTION------------------------------------------

`function saveForm(event) {.....
   event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Add error parameter to have more info about your problem : .error(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){})

Comment: `alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
 alert("Error2: " + textStatus);`

Error : (nothing)
Error2: error

Comment: use `console.log(errorThrown)` and check your browser's console.

Comment: I use firebug and I see the POST error a few seconds, but there is no information

Comment: There is an option to preserve the console log in firebug. Check it and see what exactly your problem is about.

Comment: Yes, you need to learn to debug your ajax requests. Fix your firebug or use chrome. You will see all requests done on the current page.

Comment: chrome doesn´t alert("4") so I doesnt see any log